# How to make retrieving the value from the button once it has been clicked more efficient

Tags: reactjs

basically I'm doing a kind of questionnaire, where questions are set out and with buttons you can express your choice from "little interest" to "very important" (from "1" to "4" respectively)

the method I used is this, although it doesn't seem to be the nicest/most efficient method:

```
<div className="mt-4 d-grid gap-2 col-8 mx-auto">
    <button className="btn btn-light shadow-sm btn-lg fw-normal" type="submit" value="1" onClick={e => handleAnswers(e, "value")}>Molto poco</button>
    <button className="btn btn-light shadow-sm btn-lg fw-normal" type="submit" value="2" onClick={e => handleAnswers(e, "value")}>Abbastanza</button>
    <button className="btn btn-light shadow-sm btn-lg fw-normal" type="submit" value="3" onClick={e => handleAnswers(e, "value")}>Importanti</button>
    <button className="btn btn-light shadow-sm btn-lg fw-normal" type="submit" value="4" onClick={e => handleAnswers(e, "value")}>Fondamentali</button>
</div>
```

This is the function being called:

```
    const handleAnswers = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let questionResponse = e.target.value; //=====> This is where i get the answere value
        let questionId = currentQuestionCounter;

        setAnswers([...answers, { questionId, questionResponse }]);
        nextQuestion();
    }
```

Is there any way to achieve the same result but in a more beautiful/functional way?

Comment: `{["Molto poco", ...].map((label, index) => ...)}`?

Comment: Done, grate suggetion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So probably the correct answer is between  [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)'s comment and [@mariko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12131849/mariko)'s response

Basically I did this:

```
{
["Molto poco", "Abbastanza", "Importanti", "Fondamentali"].map((label, index) => {
    return (
        <Button className="btn btn-light shadow-sm btn-lg fw-normal" type="submit" value={index + 1} onClick={handleAnswers}>{label}</Button>
        )
    })
}
```

And for the function i did this:

```
const handleAnswers = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let questionResponse = e.currentTarget.value;
    let questionId = currentQuestionCounter;

    setAnswers([...answers, { questionId, questionResponse }]);
    nextQuestion();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `e.currrentTarget.value`

```
 const handleAnswers = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let questionResponse = e.currentTarget.value;
        let questionId = currentQuestionCounter;

        setAnswers([...answers, { questionId, questionResponse }]);
        nextQuestion();
    }
```

The HTML code can be less verbose

```
<div className="mt-4 d-grid gap-2 col-8 mx-auto">
    <button className="btn btn-light shadow-sm btn-lg fw-normal" type="submit" value="1" onClick={handleAnswers}>Molto poco</button>
    <button className="btn btn-light shadow-sm btn-lg fw-normal" type="submit" value="2" onClick={handleAnswers}>Abbastanza</button>
    <button className="btn btn-light shadow-sm btn-lg fw-normal" type="submit" value="3" onClick={handleAnswers}>Importanti</button>
    <button className="btn btn-light shadow-sm btn-lg fw-normal" type="submit" value="4" onClick={handleAnswers}>Fondamentali</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your method is the most simple one to understand. Even when u look at it some later time.